# Avoid page scrolling on loading ajax content

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a div for displaying images placed at the center of a page, and below that div i've added slider displaying image thumbnails using jcarousel, clicking on thumbnail images from the slider displays the bigger image inside a div positioned just above the slider, and this is done using ajax, i mean i'm just changing the content of div to display selected image, but whenever i click on thumbnail in slider for loading image, the page gets scrolled and image is displayed, what could be the problem, pls suggest.

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
 for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
     if (this[i] == obj) { return i; }
 }
 return -1;
}

var picList = new Array();
picList.length = 0;
function showMoreVideo(move) {
    //get picture_id of currently displayed picture
    var lastId = picList[picList.length - 1];
    var firstId = picList[0];
    var curPictId = parseInt($("#hidPicId").val());

    if(move == "nxt") {
        //get the index of current picture id
        $("#divPrev").css("display", "block");
        if(curPictId == lastId) {
            $("#divNxt").css("display", "none");
            return false;
        }
        else {

            var curIdx = picList.indexOf(curPictId);

            var nxtIdx = parseInt(curIdx + 1);
            var nxtId = picList[nxtIdx];

            var hrf = "<?php echo base_url().'seeker/gallery/ajaxLoadGallery/'.$flag.'/'.$tab.'/'.$pId .'/';?>"+nxtId;
            var url = "url(<?php echo base_url() ."images/ajax_loader.gif"; ?>)";
            //$("#imgpic").css({"background-image": url, "background-repeat": "no-repeat", "background-position" : "310px 50%", "width": "650px", "height": "386px"} );
            var dataString = "";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: hrf,
                data: dataString,
                success: function(content){
                    if(content !=''){
                        $('#ajaxContent').html(content).hide().fadeIn();
                        //style="border: 1px solid #f2efea; padding: 1px;"
                        $("img[id^='img_']").css( {"border": "1px solid #f2efea", "padding":"1px"});
                        $("img[id='img_"+nxtId+"']").css("border", "1px solid <?php echo $cat_color;?>");
                         //$("#mycarouse_picture").focus();
                          //scroll(0,425) ;
                        var currentPos = parseInt(curIdx + 1);
                        $('.control_next').trigger("click", [currentPos,'0']);
                        return false;
                    }else {
                        alert("Couldn't load image. Retry later!");
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#hidPicId").val('');
            $("#hidPicId").val(nxtId);
            if(nxtId == lastId) {
                $("#divNxt").css("display", "none");
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if(move == "prev") {
        $("#divNxt").css("display", "block");
        if(curPictId == firstId) {
            $("#divPrev").css("display", "none");
            return false;
        }
        var curIdx = picList.indexOf(curPictId);
        var prevIdx = parseInt(curIdx - 1);
        var prevId = picList[prevIdx];
        var nhrf = "<?php echo base_url().'seeker/gallery/ajaxLoadGallery/'.$flag.'/'.$tab.'/'.$pId .'/';?>"+prevId;
        var url = "url(<?php echo base_url() ."images/ajax_loader.gif"; ?>)";
        //$("#imgpic").css({"background-image": url, "background-repeat": "no-repeat", "background-position" : "310px 50%", "width": "650px", "height": "386px"} );
        var dataString = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: nhrf,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(content){
                if(content !=''){
                    $('#ajaxContent').html(content).hide().fadeIn();
                    $("img[id^='img_']").css( {"border": "1px solid #f2efea", "padding":"1px"});
                    $("img[id='img_"+prevId+"']").css("border", "1px solid <?php echo $cat_color;?>");
                    //$("#mycarouse_picture").focus();
                     //scroll(0,425) ;
                    var currentPos = parseInt(curIdx - 1);
                    currentPos = (currentPos < 1) ? 0 : currentPos;
                    $('.control_prev').trigger("click", [currentPos,'0']);
                    return false;
                }else {
                    alert("Couldn't load image. Retry later!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        $("#hidPicId").val('');
        $("#hidPicId").val(prevId);
        if(prevId == firstId) {
            $("#divPrev").css("display", "none");
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
function fnChangePic(imgpath,currentLi,obj)
{

    var url = "url("+imgpath+")";
   // $(".test_sider > li").attr('id').not(":eq("+liId+")").hide();
    //$(".test_sider > li:eq("+currentLi+")").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#imgpic").css({"background": url,"background-repeat": "no-repeat","background-position":"53% 50%", "width": "650px", "height": "386px","overflow":"hidden"});
    $("img[id^='img_']").css( {"border": "1px solid #f2efea", "padding":"1px"});
    $(obj).children().css("border", "1px solid <?php echo $cat_color;?>");
    return false;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarouse_picture').jcarousel({
        auto: 0,
        scroll:8,
        visible:8,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initPictureCallback
    });


      $('.gallerythumnailimage').click(function(evt){
           //scroll(0,425) ;
          evt.preventDefault();
        var cId = $(this).children().attr("id");

        var curIdArr = cId.split("_");
        var crtId = curIdArr[1];
        if(picList.indexOf(crtId) > 0) {
            $("#divPrev").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#divPrev").hide();
        }
        if(picList.indexOf(crtId) >= (picList.length - 1)) {
            $("#divNxt").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#divNxt").show();
        }
        $("img[id^='img_']").css( {"border": "1px solid #f2efea", "padding":"1px"});
        $(this).children().css("border", "1px solid <?php echo $cat_color;?>");


      //var loading = "<div style='font-weight:bold;width: 200px; height: 95px; padding:150px 295px;line-height:400px;'><img width='64' height='64' src='<?php echo base_url() ."images/ajax_loader.gif"; ?>' /><br /><span style='margin-top:2px;line-height:40px;'>&nbsp;Loading...</span></div>";
      //$('#ajaxContent').html(loading);
       var url = "url(<?php echo base_url() ."images/ajax_loader.gif"; ?>)";
      //$("#imgpic").css({"background-image": url, "background-repeat": "no-repeat", "background-position" : "310px 50%", "width": "650px", "height": "386px"} );
      //return false;
      var dataString = "";
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: $(this).attr('rel'),
       data: dataString,
       success: function(content){           
           if(content !=''){
               $('#ajaxContent').html(content).hide().fadeIn();;
                //scroll(0,425) ;
               return false;
           }else {
               alert("Couldn't load image. Retry later!");
               return false;
           }

       }

       });

    return false; // don't let the link reload the page
  });
 return false;

});

function mycarousel_initPictureCallback(carousel)
{
    // Disable autoscrolling if the user clicks the prev or next button.
    jQuery('.control_prev').bind('click', function(event, a, b) {
       if( (a/8) < 1){
            carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(a-1));
        }
        return false;
    });
    jQuery('.control_next').bind('click', function(event, a, b) {

       if((a%8) == 0){
            carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(a+1));
        }
        return false;
    });
    carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });

};
```

Comment: could you link us to an example? or put the code into a jsfiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Can you please only include the **relevant** parts - ie. the smallest amount of code that still exhibit the problem?